# Merge 2D irregular shapes to generate 3D solid

Tags: faces, extrude

I have 2 SVG shapes. Consider them as top and bottom faces of an object. I want to 'blend' one shape to the other to create a 3D solid. They have a differing number of vertices. Am I able to do this in Blender? I have limited understanding of Blender, but from viewing various YouTube videos it strikes me that what I am attempting should be relatively straight forward?

If anyone can point me to a tutorial I'm happy to give it a go.

Thanks, Darren.

[image]

Tried the suggestion below and got this:
Are the shapes too complex (hard to believe), note number of vertices? I get the feeling there should be some control vertices that would avoid the cross-over effect?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I have some other settings to correct

Answer (score 0):

Join both objects together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) if not joined.

In Edit mode select outer edges of upper and lower parts, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and select *Bridge Edge Loop*